# View and/or edit a .cblite database from within Windows?

Tags: windows, file-format, couchbase-lite

I have a **.cblite** (couchbase-lite) database which I would like to view on a **Windows 8.1** machine. I currently see 3 approaches

- On [GitHub](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchbaseLiteViewer/releases) there seems to be a tool "CouchbaseLiteViewer" for doing just that under Mac OS,  maybe it can be ported to Windows, but it looks to me like there are quite a few dependencies
- [Their "Mobile portal" repository](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-mobile-portal/) seems to also contain the sources to roll my own tool from scratch in Java - same dependency issue
- It might be possible to **install Couchbase Server** and import the .cblite database to access through the admin interface (Futon). I tried this with an older (1.x) Couchbase Server, but could not find how to import
- If I **understood the file format**, I could maybe code something manually for my specific situation, but the file just looks like random/compressed data without any noticeable header

I am a bit lost how to continue here - can anyone **give me some pointers** of how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it `.cblite` or `.cblite2`?  Couchbase Lite moved to the `.cblite2` format in 1.2.  If you have a `.cblite` file then it is simply an SQLite file with another extension and you can view it with any SQLite editor.  `.cblite2` is a directory with either `db.sqlite3` or `db.forest.X` inside depending on the storage engine used.  You can view the former with an SQLite editor, but the latter is a bit more complicated.  If you want to write an editor, then the actual querying will not be hard (you can just use an all documents query).  The bulk of the work will just be hooking up that information to display.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! The database was encrypted, so I could read it with an SQLite viewer with the appropriate key. However I am still stuck at decrypting the attachments - it seems there is a by-file encryption key stored inside the database, for each attachment, but the viewer I use (DB Browser for SQ Lite) doesn't seem to know how to deal with this automatically...

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg One place that might trip you up is (at least in .NET) the IV is stored as the first 16 bytes of the file.  The rest of the file is the actual encrypted data.

Comment: Yes, that took me a moment to read out of the code... sadly I am doing something else wrong, I currently always end up with "bad magic number".

Comment: Well...you could always use the library itself and make a small console application using the `SymmetricKey` class and `DecryptStream`